# How to center vertically content of the table?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I have this table:

```
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{x}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

\begin{table}[ht]\footnotesize
\centering
\begin{tabular*}{0.95\textwidth }{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|llllllllllllllll|x{0.15\textwidth}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{16}{|c|}{Small text} & Long text \\ \hline 
1 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 16 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 0.9636149 \\ \hline 
\end{tabular*}
\caption{Caption}
\label{tab:Example}
\end{table}
```

How to center "Small text"?

Comment: I can't compile your example.  What table-extending packages are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't included my custom column definition. Now it should compile.

Comment: Works for me, sort of.  With the standard article class the lines don't extend all the way across, because the table is too wide for the `\textwidth`.  If I do `\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}` which shortens the margins a bit, the lines extend all the way across.  Either way, though, "small text" is centered across the first 16 columns.  Can you post a picture of what you're seeing?

Comment: @Matthew: I think the important word here is *vertical*. Think of ”long text” as something that has multiple lines. Then “small text” is aligned at the top.

Comment: Exactly. What I want to achieve is to center this "small text" vertically.

Comment: Ah.  I might have realized that if "long text" had actually been long text. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change the `p` to `m` in your definition of the `x` column type:

```
\newcolumntype{x}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{x}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]\footnotesize
\centering
\begin{tabular*}{0.95\textwidth }{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|llllllllllllllll|x{0.15\textwidth}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{16}{|c|}{Small text} & Long long long long long text \\ \hline 
1 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 16 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 0.9636149 \\ \hline 
\end{tabular*}
\caption{Caption}
\label{tab:Example}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How one would redefine `\newcolumntype` above to vertically align to the **top** of the cells?

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ | c | m{5cm} | m{5cm} | }
    \hline
    11111111 & 2222222 & 33333333 \\ \hline
    \begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a.png}
    \end{minipage}
    &
    \begin{equation*}
    \dfrac{12!-x^2}{9x^3-99}
    \end{equation*}
    & 
      \begin{itemize}
        \item item111
        \item item2222222
        \item text text text
        \item Double-click here to open the full log. \ldots
      \end{itemize}
    \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Your caption}
  \label{Your label}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```