# Which is the easiest way to center cell-content vertically?

Tags: tables, center

I'd like to center all cells content vertically.
Which is the easiest way?

```
\begin{longtable}
    \centering
    \caption{Grafs dirigits}
    \begin{tabular}{p{2cm}|p{4.5cm}|p{1.4cm}|p{1.4cm}|p{3cm}}
    \toprule
    \tabhead{Nom} & \tabhead{Polinomi característic\footnote{En l'àlgebra lineal, s'associa un polinomi a cada matriu quadrada anomenat polinomi característic. Aquest polinomi conté una gran quantitat d'informació sobre la matriu, els més significatius són els valors propis, el seu determinant i la seva traça.}} & \tabhead{Vèrtexs} & \tabhead{Arestes} & \tabhead{Representació}\\
    \midrule
        Petersen & $(x-1)^{5}(x+2)^{4}(x-3)$ & 10 & 15 & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures/Petersen.png}\\ \hline
        Coxeter & $(x-2)^{8}(x+1)^{7}(x^{2}+2x-1)^{6}(x-3)$ & 28 & 42 & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures/Coxeter.png}\\ \hline
        Clebsch & $(x+3)^{5}(x+-1)^{10}(x-5)$ & 16 & 4 & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures/Clebsch.png}\\ \hline
        Chang & $(x+12)^{5}(x+21)^{6}(x-18)$ & 28 & 168 & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures/Chang.png}\\ \hline
        Color circular & No en té & $n$ & $\frac{n^{2}-2kn+n}{2}$ & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures/Color circular.png}\\ \hline
        Horton & $(x-3)(x-1)^{14}x^{4}(x+1)^{14}(x-3)(x^{2}-5)^{3}(x^{2}-3)^{11}(x^{2}+x-3)(x^{10}-23x^{8}+188x^{6}-644x^{4}+803x^{2}-101)^{2}(x^{10}-20x^{8}+143x^{6}-437x^{4}+500x^{2}-59)$ & 96 & 144 & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures/Horton.png}\\ \hline
        Folkman & $x^{10}(x^{2}-6)^{4}(x-4)(x+4)$ & 20 & 40 & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures/Folkman.png}\\ \hline
        Gosset & $(x-9)^{7}(x+1)^{27}(x-27)(x+3)^{21}$ & 56 & 756 & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures/Gosset.png}\\ \hline
        Higman-Sims & $(x+8)^{22}(x-2)^{77}(x-22)$ & 100 & 1100 & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures/Higman-Sims.png}\\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{longtable}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example, instead of a code snippet.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos there it goes!

Comment: there it goes -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5059/197451

Comment: You can maybe use `\makecell[l]{*content here*}` in each cell, which automatically centers the content.

Comment: @jsbibra thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Use this template:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{x}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]\footnotesize
\centering
\begin{tabular*}{0.95\textwidth }{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|llllllllllllllll|x{0.15\textwidth}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{16}{|c|}{Small text} & Long long long long long text \\ \hline 
1 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 16 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 0.9636149 \\ \hline 
\end{tabular*}
\caption{Caption}
\label{tab:Example}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```